# laravel-snappy can't connect to wkhtmltopdf on live server

Tags: cpanel, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I am using snappy and wkhtmltopdf to generate pdf. The project working fine in localhost. But when I am uploading the project on the live server (my hosting provider is namecheap and the hosting i am using is their "steller plus" package), i am getting following error:

The exit status code '127' says something went wrong: stderr: "sh: publicwkhtmltopdfbinwkhtmltopdf.exe: command not found " stdout: "".....

Here is my snappy config code what i am using:

```
 'pdf' => [
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => 'public\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe' ,
        'options' => array(),
],
```

Now i have searched a while for a solution and found something like wkhtmltopdf need to be installed in the server, need to be using vps hosting etc. I am not an expert in working on cpanel and installing stuffs there. So my questions are:

How can I install wkhtmltopdf in the hosting I described?

In which location it will be installed and what changes will need to be done on the snappy config file?

Will going for a VPS hosting make this work anyway easy?